# evitar submit de um formulário com leitor de código de barras

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form name="produto" method="post" action="cadastra.php">
   <input name="cod" type='text'>
   <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
</form>
```

Bom Sempre que eu uso o leitor de código de barras ele lê o código e submete o formulário, como evito isso? Quero que apenas ele leia o código.

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso com jQuery?

Comment: Tu pode tirar o submit e qndo quiser clicar no botão pra submitar, aí sim submitar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geralmente o leitor de código de barras envia um enter após a leitura, você pode configurar o leitor para não executar o enter, ou você pode detectar ação no campo e impedir que a ação de submit seja chamada utilizando o método [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```js
$('#cod').on('keypress',function(event){
  //Tecla 13 = Enter
  if(event.which == 13) {
    //cancela a ação padrão
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="produto" method="post" action="cadastra.php">
   <input name="cod" type='text' id="cod">
   <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
</form>
```

Note que ao clicar no campo e pressionar enter o formulário não é enviado mas ao clicar no botão sim.

Answer (score 1):

O leitor de codigo de barras funciona como um teclado. Ele identifica o codigo, digita e aperta enter. vc tem que configurar o leitor e desativar a função de enter automático.

Comment: Essa é uma ideia, mas não responde a pergunta, que pede uma sugestão no cliente, `jQuery` por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Use o e.preventDefault(); Segundo a documentação do Jquery; "Se esse método for chamado, a ação padrão do evento não será acionada."

Fonte: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Exemplo:

```
$('#meu_form').submit(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Mas isso não vai evitar que o `form` seja enviado, mesmo quando desejar?

Comment: Tem razão. No caso é fazer como foi mencionado. Tratar se a tecla entre foi acionada, caso contrário envie o form.